# Is there a way to automatically detect a NFC card on an external reader?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I'm trying to automatically detect a NFC card on an external reader that's connected to the phone through OTG. The reader is already being automatically detected on connection, but to read data from the card i have to manually make the call (onNewIntent is not being called on card being near the reader).

I'm using a Digital Logic uFR Classic CS reader (https://www.d-logic.net/nfc-rfid-reader-sdk/products/ufr-classic-cs/) with MiFare Desfire Ev1 cards. Also, uFR SDK uses FTDI's d2xx Android library as it's base to connect the reader.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API manual you can enable `Asynchronous UID sending` (it is not on by default), as long as you are already listening on the com port connection with the card reader then this will cause the reader to send the UID when a card comes in to range.

When you receive the UID you can start reading the card.

It also has an option to sent the UID when a card goes out of range.

(Note not used an external NFC reader, just use the inbuilt ones in phones).